# AWS Code Build: Is it possible to highlight my Errors in Red and Success in Green in code build log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to highlight my logs in AWS Code Build
Display the errors in bold font and Errors in Red and Success in Green and my Code is in Javascript the logs are highlighted in the terminal but not in AWS code Build logs.
Any help ?

Comment: Pretty sure Code Build just writes its logs to CloudWatch. You can download the logs from CWL and format them however you like locally, but its not supported by the product AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a proper way to do this, but I have found the following:

- Including the word  `Error` in a string will color the whole line red. There must be a space before Error and the first E must be capitalized.
- Including the phrase `Running command` will color the line blue.
- Including the phrase `Entering phase` will color the string blue.

The first one may be useful.